# React Native Search Closing After Each Key Stroke

Tags: javascript, react-native, search, state

I have a search bar that hits an API passing in a search key (also using `debounce` to regulate the call), and returns the data to pass into a state and use that state array to populate my `flatlist`.

Debounce code:

```
const debouncedFetchData = debounce((query, cb) => {
  fetchData(query, cb);
}, 300);

const fetchData = async (query, cb) => {
  returnUnSortedWorkouts(query).then(items => {
    cb(items);
  });
};
```

Search Trigger Code:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    debouncedFetchData(searchKey, d => {
      const groups = d.map(y => ({
        id: y.id,
        name: y.name,
        thumbnail: y.thumbnail,
      }));
      setDataSet(groups);
      setsearching(false)
    });
  }, [searchKey]);
```

search bar and flatlist:

```
<SearchBar
            onChangeText={e => {setSearchKey(e), setsearching(true)}}
            autoFocus
            defaultValue={searchKey}
            style={[
              {
                width: '100%',
              },
              tailwind('my-2'),
            ]}
          />
        </View>

        {!searching && (
          <FlatList
            style={{ width: '100%' }}
            data={dataSet}
            keyExtractor={(item, index) => {
              return index;
            }}
            renderItem={({ item, index }) => {
              return (
                <View style={tailwind(`mt-[7px]`)}>
                  //custom component 
                  <RecommendedWorkout
                    navigation={navigation}
                    id={item.id}
                   // (other info not added)
                  />
                </View>
              );
            }}
          />
        )}
```

I am happy to add any other context to help be able to understand the dynamic. My guess is the state is causing re-rendering, but I cant figure out how to stop this.

Answer (score 0):

To fix, I needed to move

```
<SearchBar
            onChangeText={e => {setSearchKey(e), setsearching(true)}}
            autoFocus
            defaultValue={searchKey}
            style={[
              {
                width: '100%',
              },
              tailwind('my-2'),
            ]}
          />
```

out of the function.